# Node.js - Infinite Loop in Custom Code (Custom business logic)

Tags: node.js, business-logic

Hi I'm making a business application in which user can write his custom code and execute it.
How can i handle situations when the custom code generates infinite loops ?

A way is to handle each request in separate child process and kill that process on request completion but if there are  thousands of users this doesn't seem to be appropriate. What else can be done in such cases ?

Comment: Application of such type should use `try { ... } catch(e) { ... }` for custom code. That way you will catch all errors and it won't kill your server.

Comment: I don't have control over what user's custom code is. I need something better than try { ... } catch(e) { ... }

Comment: You can try node js http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html. Also, will you like to share knowledge (so far) via a blog or so. I am also thinking of some similar type of work and it seems the interest for such work is growing.

Comment: Unless you're going to put this into a process that you can kill if it becomes non-response, or put restrictions on the incoming code, or modify the V8 engine there's not much you can do.   You can only monitor JS from outside the process.

Comment: Turing has proved that it was impossible to analyse the code and find the infinite loop. Then you'll need a timeout.

Comment: I handle all calls in Domain but its onError has no effect during infinite loop situation.

Comment: @Vinz243 Some tasks can be heavy and take some time. How can i decide a timeout period if i am not sure if process is blocked or just processing some heavy task ?

Comment: @jfriend00 or he could create a procedure for the user to kill a process and a procedure to bill user for usage.  Then the halting problem becomes some one else's problem.

Comment: You can't know the exact difference between a legitimately busy task and a stuck loop.  All you can do is pick a time (a guess) that is unlikely to be legitimate code and go with that.  That's what the browser does for its own JS execution.  It is not always right, but is usually right.  There simply is no way to tell what long running task is or isn't legitimate.